# How can you center align two buttons in a form side by side?

Tags: html, css

How can I align these buttons side by side in the middle of the form. Anything I have tried has not worked. I have tried to add margin-left: 500px, but the buttons just ned up displaying vertically under each other. I have also tried to align-item center and this has also not worked. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```css
input[type="submit"] {
  color: black;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="button"] {
  color: black;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  margin-right: 400px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<form style="justify-content:center; display: flex" id="GetInTouch" onsubmit="callFunction()">
  <div class="container">
    <h1> Contact Form </h1>
    <label for="first_name">
        <b> First Name *</b>
      </label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
    <label for="surname">
        <b> Surname *</b>
      </label>
    <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" />
    <label for="email">
        <b> Email *</b>
      </label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required /> <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="button" onclick="resetFunction()" value="Reset">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: use `flex-direction: row;`

Comment: @maxkroon unfortunately this did not work :(

Comment: well the css way of doing it is by setting the parent of the buton to display: flex; and ad flex-direction: row;  i would suggest you add that to the parent which is not <form> but the div with the class: container